# How to deal with serialization and deserialization of objects with dependencies

Tags: serialization, dependencies, deserialization, circular-dependency

Suppose I have two objects that depend on each other or other objects(so use references to these objects) and I need to save/restore their "state" from/to disk. Since storing pointers to disk does not produce correct results on restore, how do we keep the dependencies correct on restore?

e.g.,

```
class A {
   B b;
}

class B {
{
   A a;
}
```

(or more complex chains that may have n-cycles of dependencies)

A a = deserialize(Adata)
B b = deserialize(Bdata)

(and suppose we need a.b = b and b.a = a)

I'm thinking that having unique hashes for objects with lazy evaluation would solve the problem but maybe there are better ways? (if I have a unique hash then it is easy to find the object to use and also to save and restore the object(basically the hash acts as a pointer but is always valid(since it is unique and never changes))